# Cómo crear formulario log-in Laravel básico

Tags: mysql, laravel, web, eloquent

La cosa está en que recién termine de crear un formulario de registro *manual*, y no usando el "make:auth" o "ui:auth de la nueva versión de laravel".

*El problema ahora está en que no encuentro información válida sobre cómo crear un log-in para poder loguear a los usuarios, podría alguien enseñarme a crear sencillito pero funcional?*

**Tabla Usuario[MIGRACIÓN]**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->tinyInteger('telefono')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Método dónde registro los usuarios en el controlador[CONTROLLER]**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();

        $user->name = request('name');
        $user->email = request('email');
        $user->password = request('password');

        $user->save();

        return 'Usuario creado con éxito';
    }
```

Comment: ¿por qué no usar el que incluye Laravel? O podrías inspirarte en ese para creaer tu versión.

Comment: No voy a usar ningun Make:auth ni nada por el estilo , me interesa poder entender lo máximo posible el código. Gracias @Shaz

Comment: Si tanto te interesa entender el código, entonces ve y lee el código de Laravel que recibe las credenciales para iniciar sesión, cuando lo entiendas, podrás crear tu propio formulario, con los campos necesarios.

Comment: Al código que te refieres es a todo el código que hay  en el**trait AuthenticatesUsers**? Una vez lo logre entender ,puedo coger algunos trozos de ese código y usarlas en mi propio controlador, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay una sección en la [documentación oficial de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#authenticating-users) dedicada a esto.

Para autenticar manualmente a un usuario debes de usar el método `attempt` que corresponde al facade `Auth`, toma el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function autenticar(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            //Las credenciales coinciden
            //Código para usuario autenticado aquí
        }else{
           //Código para usuario incorrecto aquí
        }
    }
}
```

El método `attempt` recibe como parámetro un array en formato `['llave' => 'valor']`. La llave la comparará con la columna de tu base de datos de la tabla de usuarios que tengas especificada en el archivo `config/auth.php`:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/

'table' => 'users',
```

También es importante mencionar que el login lo puedes hacer en cualquier controlador que desees dentro del método que desees, solo asegúrate de incluir el facade `Auth` al inicio de tu clase del controlador. Tampoco se tiene que llamar "logincontroller", eres libre de nombrarlo como desees.

Comment: Definitavamente, es lo que estaba buscando, ya que estaba un poco perdido, muchas gracias Aaron! 

Con el enlace sería suficiente, pero ya así detallado está mejor.

Gracias compañero!

Comment: @FitnessDeveloper Si, lo que pasa es que cuando respondes aparte del enlace debes de poner tu explicación porque el enlace puede cambiarse, moverse, etc, entonces si dejas solo el enlace y ocurre esto no habría respuesta.